# Service, Model e Repository: onde deve ficar lógica,validações e possível comunicação externa?

Tags: php, laravel, orientação-a-objetos, ddd

Estou fazendo um pequeno projeto para fins de aprendizagem usando Laravel, esse sistema gira em torno de dois "models", `Conta` e `Transacao`.

uma `Conta` tem nome e saldo, uma `Transacao` tem conta_origem, conta_destino, valor e detalhes.

Criei repositórios e services para os dois "Models" para encapsular a comunicação com o Eloquent e o Controller.

Estrutura de exemplo da `Transacao`

```
class TransactionController extends Controller
{
   
    public function transfer(Request $request, TransactionService $transactionService)
    {
      
      try {

            $transactionService->transfer(
                $request->from, $request->to, $request->amount, $request->details
            );

            return response()->json(['success' => 'true']);

        } catch (\Throwable $error) {

            return response()->json([
                'success' => 'false',
                'errors' => $error
            ], Response::BAD_REQUEST);
        }
    }

}
```

- 

```
class TransactionService
    {
    
        public function findById(int $id, TransactionRepositoryContract $TransactionRepository)
        {
            return $TransactionRepository->findById($id);
        }
    
        public function transfer($from, $to, $amount, $details)
        {
            $TransactionEloquentRepository = new TransactionEloquentRepository;
            $AccountEloquentRepository = new AccountEloquentRepository;
    
            $fromAccount = $AccountEloquentRepository->findById($to);
    
            if($fromAccount->getAmount() < $amount) {
                throw new Exception('source account does not have enough balance');
            }
    
            //db transaction
    
            $TransactionEloquentRepository->create([
                'from' => $from
                'to' => $to,
                'amount' => $amount,
                'details' => $details
            ]);
    
            $AccountEloquentRepository->update($from, [
                'balance' => $fromAccount->balance - $amount
            ]);
    
            //db end transaction
        }
    }
```

O `$TransactionEloquentRepository` basicamente só encapsula algumas chamadas pro Eloquent.

As dúvidas são as seguintes:

1 - Esta implementação está correta? o service que deve lidar com essas validações (verificar se uma conta é válida, se possui saldo suficiente, criar saldo, diminuir saldo etc) e pode se comunicar com repositories externos?

1.1 - O laravel possui a validação com FormRequest, mas essa validação também deve estar no service?

2 - Em caso de falha em qualquer etapa desse processo, quem deve lançar exceptions e tratar exceptions? só o controller deve tratar?

3 - É errado usar as transactions do Eloquent nos Repositories? visto que considerando abstração, nem todos os bancos tem o conceito de transações

Answer (score 3):

Vou te passar um pouco da minha experiência!

Não acredito que existam abordagens totalmente certas ou erradas, existem maneiras diferentes de implementar e cada uma vai ter seus prós e contras.

Primeiro ponto que eu mudaria, seria a camada de Repository, pois você está instanciando ele direto no método transfer, e está chamando direto o RepositoryEloquent, para mim, o ideal é que você coloque o Repository no construtor do Service e não use ele direto e sim uma interface, pois você teria e flexibilidade no futuro de implementar com outras situações, como uma chamada de API para um sistema de terceiros, por exemplo, daí você trataria o Bind da injeção de dependência em um RepositoryServiceProvider por exemplo, informando que TransactionRepositoryInterface vai usar o TransactionRepositoryEloquent, outro ponto importante que você ganha usando injeção de dependência é que quando você for criar os testes unitários, vai ser mais simples de você criar um MOCK dos Repositories para poder testar apenas a regra do TransactionService.

Quanto as validações, eu costumo separar em validações de Inputs de Dados e validações de Regras de Negócio.

As validações de Inputs de dados, eu crio uma classe de Validator, exemplo TransactionValidator e injeto ela no service e chamo a validação logo que entro no método transfer, Lembrando de seguir o mesmo princípio de utilizar Interface para caso precise implementar outros tipos de validações, vai ser somente trocar a injeção de dependência.

Quanto as validações de regra de negócio, depende do projeto, as vezes ficam na classe de Validator que está separada ou dentro do próprio TransactionService, vai depender do que eu achar que faz mais sentido para o entendimento naquele momento, se for algo que não acredito que possa ser modificado, geralmente fica dentro do próprio Service, se for algo que eu acho que pode ser mudado no futuro, tendo a colocar na classe de Validator externa.

Não costumo usar o FormRequest do Laravel, pois geralmente uso os Services em outros contextos, como chamadas de CLI, Integrações via WebSocket, Crons, etc, em que não acontecem uma requisição HTTP, então acho que a validação pelo FormRequest te limita a isso, por isso, crio a classe de Validator separada e injeto ela no Service, que tanto pelo Controller, CLI, Cron, etc, em que o Service for chamado, ele vai executar a validação.

Quanto a parte de lançar exceção, geralmente eu lanço quando tem algum problema de validação e deixo o Controller, CLI, Cron, etc, validarem isso, até porque eu posso ter um Controller que chama vários Services, ou um Service que chama mais outros Services, então deixar a borda tratar as Exceções para saber o que vai retornar, acaba sendo melhor, pois ela pode retornar um status HTTP CODE diferente, ou mandar uma mensagem de log no CLI, etc.

O Mesmo princípio eu sigo para o tratamento de transação no banco de dados, deixo sempre para a borda fazer esse tratamento, ou seja, Controller, Command, Job, Listener, etc.
PS.: No caso do Job e do Listener, so deixo eles tratarem, quando eles são assíncronos, senão, como eles não são a borda da aplicação, não uso neles, vou usar no Controller, no Command, etc

E quanto a usar transações de banco no Repository, não costumo usar, devido as explicações acima de como eu uso transação.

Espero ter ajudado!
Um abraço!

Comment: Muito obrigado pela resposta, uma dúvida, no caso do transfer, eu injetaria as duas interfaces de repositórios no construct? porque nem todos os métodos vão usar o AccountRepository.


Ou acha melhor eu criar um Service especifico pro Transfer, e nele injetar as duas interfaces de repositório? 

Sendo: TransactionController.transfer -> TransferService -> Transaction e Account Repository no __construct, e dentro do TransferService, outro método, makeTransfer, que lidaria com essas regras e lançaria exceções, boa abordagem?